# UIScrollView not scrolling in modal, Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am working on a project in which I have to display a ViewController modally, however, the scrollview does not seem to work properly. It does not scroll. Instead of directly adding to scrollview, I added a view inside the scrollview which then I would add my data to. I checked that the contentsize of scrollview is much larger than the actual width of the scrollview, but yet, it does not scroll. I disabled auto-layout and nothing changes. Here is my code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VenueViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

    static var marker : Marker = Marker(v: "Error", lat: 1, lon: 1, az: 1, dist: 1000)

    @IBOutlet weak var viewInsideScrollView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDownView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var upcomingEventLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var venueNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentEventLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var upcomingEventScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentEventImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        upcomingEventScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        upcomingEventScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        upcomingEventScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        upcomingEventScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        dropDownView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        if VenueViewController.marker.getVenueName() == "Error" {
            return
        }


        if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
            self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.backgroundView.layer.zPosition = 0
            self.dropDownView.layer.zPosition = 1
            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = self.backgroundView.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.backgroundView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        } else {
            self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }


        venueNameLabel.text = VenueViewController.marker.getVenueName()
        currentEventLabel.text = VenueViewController.marker.getEvents()[0].getName()
        ArtemisHelper.titleImageLoadView(imageView: currentEventImageView, event: VenueViewController.marker.getEvents()[0])

        loadUpcomingEvents()
    }

    func loadUpcomingEvents(){
        for event in VenueViewController.marker.getEvents(){
            if event.getName() == currentEventLabel.text{
                //continue
            }
            let eventTitleLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
            eventTitleLabel.text=event.getName() + " " + event.getLocalDate()
            eventTitleLabel.frame.size.width = dropDownView.frame.width
            eventTitleLabel.frame.size.height = 20

            eventTitleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.viewInsideScrollView.frame.minX, y: self.viewInsideScrollView.bounds.minY, width: self.viewInsideScrollView.frame.width, height: eventTitleLabel.frame.size.height)

            eventTitleLabel.frame = eventTitleLabel.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.upcomingEventScrollView.contentSize.height)
            self.viewInsideScrollView.addSubview(eventTitleLabel)

            self.upcomingEventScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.upcomingEventScrollView.contentSize.width, height: self.upcomingEventScrollView.contentSize.height+eventTitleLabel.frame.height)
            self.viewInsideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: self.upcomingEventScrollView.bounds.minX, y: self.upcomingEventScrollView.bounds.minY, width: self.upcomingEventScrollView.frame.width, height: self.upcomingEventScrollView.contentSize.height)

        }
        print(self.viewInsideScrollView.frame.height)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
        let obstacleViewFrame = self.view.convert(dropDownView.frame, from: dropDownView.superview)

        if !obstacleViewFrame.contains(touchLocation) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: From the Main Storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking apart the code piece by piece, I found out that DonMag was right in the sense that there was a transparent view that was covering the scrollview.

```
    self.backgroundView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Here, when I add the subview, this ends up covering the scrollview even though I set the zPosition to something lower than the scrollview. I added a view adjacent to backgroundView and added the blur effect view to that, which allowed me to still access the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

There are many advantages to using constraints and auto-layout, but you certainly can do what you want *without* it.

Your "add labels and set frames" loop is very convoluted. Take a look at this approach:

```
func loadUpcomingEvents(){

    // this is our starting Label frame
    //  at 0,0 and dropDownViewWidth x 20 height
    var labelRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dropDownView.frame.width, height: 20)

    for event in VenueViewController.marker.getEvents(){

        // instantiate a new label, using the current labelRect for the frame
        let eventTitleLabel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: labelRect)

        // set the text of the label
        eventTitleLabel.text=event.getName() + " " + event.getLocalDate()

        // add the label to the "inside" view
        self.viewInsideScrollView.addSubview(eventTitleLabel)

        // increment the Y position of labelRect by the Height of labelRect
        labelRect.origin.y += labelRect.size.height

    }

    // labelRect is now the frame of the "next label" in the list, 
    //  if there was a next label,
    //  so we can use its Y position for the Height of the "inside" view
    viewInsideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dropDownView.frame.width, height: labelRect.origin.y)

    // and, we set the scroll view's contentSize to the size of the "inside" view
    upcomingEventScrollView.contentSize = viewInsideScrollView.frame.size
}
```

Comment: Do you set scrollView.contentSize? Autolayout settings(when it was enabled)?

Comment: Last line sets the `.contentSize`. OP is not showing any auto layout constraints on `viewInsideScrollView`, and his/her code is clearly not assigning any.

Comment: I shifted all this code into viewDidLayoutSubviews() and it still didn't work, which I thought should even with auto layout?

Comment: You need to provide more information... Are the labels showing up where you expect them? Do they extend beyond the frame of the scroll view? After they are visible on the screen, can you set a breakpoint in your `touchesBegan` function and check the actual frame of the scroll view, the frame of the `viewInsideScrollView` and the `.contentSize` of the scroll view, to determine what may be incorrect? Do you possibly have some other transparent view covering the scroll view which is preventing the scrolling?

Comment: The views in the scrollview are showing in their respective locations and everything looks fine, but it just doesnt move when I drag down on the scrollview. I dont think that there is an invisible layer; wouldn't it show in the view controller?

Comment: Do you have enough "events" so that you have labels extending past the bottom of the scroll view?

Comment: By the way - this absolutely should **NOT** go in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ... that can be called multiple times, and you only want to add labels ONCE.

Comment: Oh, thanks for telling me! Yea, I made sure that there were enough labels such that the content size was much larger than the bound or frame size of the scrollview.

Comment: Maybe the touchesBegan function is messing around with things?